# Possible Buffer Overflow During String Concatenation

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I am new to C++. My program is crashing and I am trying to find out why. At some point of the code, I generate a random number and I copy a file with the original filename followed by the number

```
char CopyPath[MAX_PATH];
SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_MYMUSIC, NULL, 0, CopyPath);
int randomNumber = 101 + rand()%1000000000;
char randomBuffer[15];
itoa(randomNumber, randomBuffer, 10);

char computerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH+1];
DWORD size = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH;
if(!GetComputerName(computerName, &size))
    strcat(computerName, "FAIL");
strcat(CopyPath,"\\");
strcat(CopyPath, computerName);
strcat(CopyPath, "-");
strcat(CopyPath, randomBuffer);
copyFile(oldpath, CopyPath);
```

I suspect the crash happens somewhere here. My question is, since I haven't declared all the values of CopyPath, there is a crash. Should i declare it as

```
char CopyPath[MAX_PATH] = {'\0'}
```

Could this be the problem??

Comment: This code is not C++. Retagged accordingly. (In C++ you would use `std::string` and save yourself the headache)

Comment: @Billy: Don't do that.  Even code that would compile in C (and this isn't valid C90) might act subtly different in C++.  Knowing the actual language being used is important.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74538/disallow-the-tagging-of-questions-with-both-c-and-c-tags/86338#86338

Comment: @Ben: In the general case that is true, but that is not the case for this code. People watching the C tag would be better at answering it.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: I beg your pardon for entering the discussion without invitation but I totally agree with Ben Voigt. As long as C++ compiler accepts this code - then it is `C++ enough` to be tagged as such. Moreover, for this case people from both C and C++ worlds should be equally good enough at answering this.

Comment: @Billy: Are you implying that using character arrays is illegal in C++?

Comment: @David: Yes, for this purpose, that is effectively what I'm saying. This is not C++, it is C. The languages are different. Just because C++ compilers happen to be able to compile C for backwards compatibility reasons, does not mean correct code written in C is also correct for C++.

Comment: @Billy: just because there's another way to do it in C++ that doesn't exist in C doesn't mean that this particular example isn't valid C++.

Comment: @Graeme: I guess we can agree to disagree then.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> if(!GetComputerName(computerName, &size))
>     strcat(computerName, "FAIL");
> ```

This should be `strcpy`, as there's no valid string in `computerName` to append to.

Also, you probably should be calling `SHGetFolderPathA` since you are passing a buffer of `char` (and not `TCHAR`).

Comment: +1, for finding the correct error in within a number of suspicious lines :)

Answer (score 0):

Prefer using std::string than C array for holding string info like that as it provides proper copying and concatenation through = and + operators.

Comment: @DeadMG: No, it isn't. C++ strings are going to choke on this as well. A stringstream won't choke, but that is a different question.

Comment: @DeadMG: Folks, I'm afraid you haven't read the question - because this IS NOT the answer. The question was about the cause of a crash and not about how the SO community would have rewritten his code to be more C++ like.

Comment: not using char fixed size array is the correct C++ way of doing this. This is C code, so either the stuff get moved to C or the solution proposed is C++. Correct string manipulation in C++ is done through std::string and the stringstreams.

Comment: Hogwash. std::string and streams are a part of C++ but nothing says they _must_ be used over char arrays. As I mentioned above, just because there's another way (even a _better_ way) to do it, doesn't mean this way is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what causes the crash in your case. My guess that it must be a buffer overrun problem. Do you consider space for the ending `\0` character in MAX_PATH constant?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've understood from other comments that your code is not very good (at least due to style and possible buffer overruns).

Taking into account only your specific question - you are right - problem is in the uninitialized char array, which doesn't represent a C-string because it has to be zero-terminated. As you probably know `strcat` works on C strings. So changing from:

```
  char CopyPath[MAX_PATH]; // this is not a C-string
```

to

```
  char CopyPath[MAX_PATH] = {0}; // this is a C-string (empty though)
```

will fix this particular problem.

**EDIT:** this approach should be taken with any buffer that you are going to use with `strcat` as concatenation target, which in your case is `computerName`

Comment: I thought that first, but `SHGetFolderPath` doesn't concatenate, it writes out a NUL-terminated string to the provided buffer.  Unless of course it fails.